# Realizar este tipo de SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla MYSQL, donde un usuario ingresa 2 tipos de medidas ANCHO y LARGO.
Le largo es declarado como nombre de la columna. 
Mi duda si es posible realizar un tipo de `SELECT`  de acuerdo a las medida de que estan declaradas como en la tabla como columnas siendo que son los largo.

Ejemplo si el `ANCHO` es 200 y el `LARGO` 2100. El resultado seria `630.2`

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Producto | ANCHO     | 2000   | 2100  | 2200  |
-----------|-----------|--------|-------|-------|
| Item 1.1 |    100    |  598.5 | 620.2 | 750.2 |     
| Item 1.1 |    200    |  602.3 | 630.2 | 770.3 |     
| Item 1.2 |    300    |  620.3 | 690.2 | 800.3 |
|----------|-----------|--------|-------|-------|
```

Para mi seria lo ideal cambiar el formato de la tabla agregando la columna LARGO con las medidas y realizar el SELECT con un `>=`. O lo otro obtener  el resultado y guardar en un array y buscar el largo mas cercano en el array.

Espero haberme explicado bien, me costo entenderme ami mismo y al programador que me envio esto hehe.

Comment: Si, considero que si se pudiera cambiar el formato de la tabla sería genial

Comment: Pues si normalizas puede que hasta sobren la mayoría de datos, pues parecen ser valores calculados. Entonces, podrías guardar solamente los valores de `ANCHO` y de `LARGO` y aquellos valores que sean calculados, hacer el cálculo in situ, según la necesidad en ese contexto. Muchas veces es mejor hacerlo así que estar guardando datos calculados.